# Finding the $g'$ of 2 functions

Tags: calculus

I am given that $g$ is defined implicitly as a function of  $x$ by the following equations, where  $f$ is a given function of one variable. How do you find an expression for $g'$?

**(a)**
$$xg^2=f(x) - g^3$$

> For **(a)**, I did this:
>   $$\begin{align*}xg^2 + x(2g)(g') &= f'(x) -3g^2g' \\g' &= \frac{f'(x)-g^2}{2xg+3g^2}\end{align*}$$

**UPDATE:** Taking into account the comments, the final answer for (a) is: 
$$\begin{align*}g^2 + x(2g)(g') &= f'(x) -3g^2g' \\g' &= \frac{f'(x)-g^2}{2xg+3g^2}\end{align*}$$
**(b)**
$$f(2x+g)= x+g^2$$

> For **(b)**, I did this:
>   $$\begin{align*} \begin{bmatrix}f'(2x+g)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2+g'\end{bmatrix} &= 1+2gg' \\g' &= \frac{1-2f'(2x+g)}{f(2x+g)-2g}\end{align*}$$

Am I missing out on any steps? The answers look weird to me, especially **(b)**.

**UPDATE:**  Final ans. given in the comments with a tick.

Comment: The first line of (a), that $xg^2$ should be $g^2$.

Comment: On part $a$, I think you just have a transcription error; the first $x$ shouldn't be there. Your answer reflects this fact, just not the writing. For $b$, the $f$ in the denominator should be $f'$, but otherwise I think it looks good.

Comment: Except for the line that @GerryMyerson has said, I think they're correct. The difference between these and the expressions for a function that may be used to see, is that here you're getting to a differential equation for $g$, instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit differentiation as well:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(2x + g) &= x + g^2 \\
(f'(2x + g))(2 + g') &= 1 + (2g)(g') \\
2(f'(2x + g)) + (g')(f'(2x + g)) &= 1 + (2g)(g') \\
(g')(f'(2x + g)) - (g')(2g) &= 1 - 2f'(2x + g) \\
(g')(f'(2x + g) - 2g) &= 1 - 2f'(2x + g) \\
g' &= \frac{1 - 2f'(2x + g)}{f'(2x + g) - 2g}
\end{align*}
$$

Please do tell me if you need further explanation.